# Is there a more sensible way of writing this regular expression?

Tags: python, regex

The following regular expression is written in the Python dialect:

```
^(    )*#(\s+\S(.*\S)?)?$
```

Can anyone see a better way to wright this? For those not sure what it is saying:

- It matches an entire line.
- The lines starts with any multiple of four spaces.
- A hash-tag follows those spaces.
- Either nothing or the following comes after the hash-tag:

  - At least one whitespace character follows the hash-tag.
  - One non-whitespace character comes after those.
  - Either nothing or the following comes next:

    - Any number of characters follow.
    - The last character is a non-whitespace character.

Can it be simplified anymore than this?

```
^(    )*#(\s.*\S)?$
```

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, nobody in history has ever praised regexps for readability ;-)

Comment: I think what you have is fine. I don't immediately see a way to condense it. I would include those bullet points as comments somewhere, though.

Comment: How about this one `^( {4})*#(\s.*\S)?$`, although there is no reduction in length of the regexp?

Comment: @NeerajT: At least the compiler debug output is shorter.

Comment: so trailing whitespace is absolutely not allowed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way to re-write the regexp to enhance readability (to reduce the chance to count consecutive whitespaces):

```
^( {4})*#(\s.*\S)?$
```

In the words of @Noctis, it shortens the compiler debug output.

Procedure to get `(\s.*\S)?` from `(\s+\S(.*\S)?)?`

`\s+` => `\s(\s)*`

`\S(.*\S)?` =>  `\S` or `\S.*\S`  => `(\S.*)?\S`

`(\s+\S(.*\S)?)?` => `(\s(\s)*(\S.*)?\S)?` => `(\s.*\S)?` because `(\s)*(\S.*)?` => `.*`

Comment: The `(\s.*\S)?` substitution for `(\s+\S(.*\S)?)?` is the big readability win here to my mind. Without that, two separate patterns for the possibilities of 
"Either nothing or the following comes after the hash-tag:" might make sense.

Answer (score 4):

You could always use the [`re.VERBOSE`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.X) flag and add the explanation you gave here as comments.  :)